# Passing PHP arguments with empty double apostrophe

Tags: php

I am trying to understand the use of double apostrophe on PHP function arguments. The code looks like this:

```
public function get_list($men="",$women="",$other=""){
       // TO-DO
}
```

What is the use of the double apostrophe in the arguments as in `$men=""` and can you please recommend where I can read about it?

Comment: The double-quotes you see indicate an empty string. In a function parameter a value presented like this is a default used if no argument is provided in the function call. See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clear answer. You could have included it as an answer but its fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that if there's no value within these variables then it'll by default take empty values.

```
public function get_list($men="",$women="",$other=""){
    echo "Hello $men or $women , $other";
}
```

Calling function without parameters

```
get_list();//Hello  or  ,
```

Calling function with first parameters value

```
get_list('Lenny Carmi');//Hello Lenny Carmi or ,
```

Calling function with second parameters value

```
get_list('','Lenny Carmi');//Hello or Lenny Carmi ,
```

Calling function with third parameters value

```
get_list('','','Lenny Carmi');//Hello or , Lenny Carmi
```

Calling function with all parameters value

```
get_list('men','women','other');//Hello men or women , other
```

[Check Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 2):

They are [default argument values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) containing an empty string.